# How to make Java GUI full screen and similar to Playstation 3

Tags: java, user-interface

## Case

This is not really a games project. Its a project which runs in full screen for showing video conferencing, and watching TV in high definition, and is controlled from a Remote control.

## Wish:

- I am looking for GUI libraries.
  Is there only this method available for developing full screen applications?
  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html
- I need a nice looking GUI with nice GUI buttons/grid/multiple video screen 9 or 4 and good layout. (OR something similar to VCR or DVD player GUI in full screen) 
  For example 
  [image: example]
  Question: Which Java GUI libraries i can use to make such above user interfaces?

Comment: Please see above. Update with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing with a custom PLAF, some nice icons for the buttons, a couple of background image panels (custom component, easy to create) and nested layouts (mostly AWT with some Swing) should be able to achieve that effect.  You could then put the UI into whatever top level container, `JFrame`, undecorated `JFrame`, `JWindow` etc. that best suits it.

See also the [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html) lesson in the Java Tutorial.

Comment: Do you mean i can achieve exactly the same full screen and UI, without even using any Java2D??? This module can be a final goal ex: http://www.skypeassets.com/content/dam/skype/images/site/features/group-video-call-hero-main-01.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You could build your GUI on the [Slick 2D Library](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/). That way, you can use OpenGL to produce high-performance pretty GUI elements. I think Slick also has some support for GUI coding already.

Comment: Thanks! I will have "Samsung LN32A550 32-Inch 1080p LCD HDTV" where 1 full screen video and some other case there will be 6/5 participants live communication. Its correct choice still, you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use Java2D, but personally I would rather use C++ for making this type of GUI. Much better graphics libraries and a much bigger graphics programming community.

Comment: Thank you, for your suggest, but i prefer to do this pure in Java. Again moving to another language and breaking native Java shifted staffs makes more cross platform complication, i already learned few lessons working with Java and using other native codes for Video platform.